# How to determine whether user has accepted or denied a permission in Android?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I have an application which ask for permission from the user to start the device's bluetooth. I want to know whether if the user accepted or denied the permission.
Is there any method to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You must override onRequestPermissionsResult method.
For example, here you check if user granted permision for access to his location:

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               //Do something here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, before that when you ask your permission you must determine your requestCode, which will be also sent to this method, when the user will be asked for permission. So it would be something like here:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
```

So now, my requestCode is equal to 1(and i am checking that later in my onActivityRestult method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well in case of bluetooth this is not working. I need to detect whether user pressed "Ok" button or the "Cancel" button of the permission dialog.

Comment: So in that case use debugger, and see what you have in your grantResults array. In case, when user accept this, the permission element from this array should be equal to PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED. Check this, also in debugger in different scenario. Also you must apply my solution from Location example to Bluetooth. So you should change only one line from my solution.